# How to check AWS Amplify Query has finished Executing before continuing code execution?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, multithreading, aws-amplify

For a Java Amplify Query such as:

```
Amplify.API.query(
    ModelQuery.get(Todo.class, id),
    response ->{ 
          Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", ((Todo) response.getData()).getName());
      },
    error ->{ 
        Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", error.toString(), error); 
    }
);
```

I want to check that this query finishes executing before continuing with code execution. This is because my code relies on the outcome of the query , and the query must finish first in order to determine the outcome.

I notice that Amplify Queries are created on a separate thread from the main thread therefore it is possible that the query can begin, and the code on the main thread can continue executing independently. That is why it is necessary for me to find out how I can make my main thread wait until the query finishes executing.

So far I have tried using

- CountDown Latch
- Timer
- Blocking Boolean
- While loop which checks for an atomic boolean value every second for
  5 seconds (using thread.sleep)

None of which I have managed to get working.

The closest I got it to working was when I check for the atomic boolean update within a certain amount of time. However it doesn't always work because even if I write this query first and then the rest of my logic (that runs on the main thread), sometimes the main thread will just execute that logic before the query, in which case "blocking" calls remain indefinitely blocked because the main thread does not get chance to even trigger the execution of the query.

Please can someone help, if you have a tried and tested sample that works that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to to achieve this by implementing a callback:

```
interface QueryCompletedCallback {
    void executeCallback(Boolean completed);
}
```

I put the Query in its own method with the callback and call the callback once the query is complete for example:

```
public void getTodo(String id, , QueryCompletedCallback callback) {
    Amplify.API.query(
        ModelQuery.get(Todo.class, id),
        response ->{ Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", ((Todo) response.getData()).getName()); callback.executeCallback(true); },
        error ->{ Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", error.toString(), error); callback.executeCallback(false);}
    );
}
```

Then where I am calling the method, I ensure I pass a `new QueryCompletedCallback`. Which then means I can access the callback result in the override method.